# Optimization and testability at the same time - how to break up code into smaller units

Tags: c++, class, function, optimization

I am trying to break up a long "main" program in order to be able to modify it, and also perhaps to unit-test it. It uses some huge data, so I hesitate:

What is best: to have function calls, with possibly extremely large (memory-wise) data being passed,

(a) by value, or

(b) by reference

(by extremely large, I mean maps and vectors of vectors of some structures and small classes... even images... that can be really large)

(c) Or to have private data that all the functions can access ? That may also mean that main_processing() or something could have a vector of all of them, while some functions will only have an item... With the advantage of functions being testable.

My question though has to do with optimization, while I am trying to break this monster into baby monsters, I also do not want to run out of memory.

It is not very clear to me how many copies of data I am going to have, if I create local variables.

Could someone please explain ?

Edit: this is not a generic "how to break down a very large program into classes". This program is part of a large solution, that is already broken down into small entities.

The executable I am looking at, while fairly large, is a single entity, with non-divisible data. So the data will either be all created as member variable in a single class, which I have already created, or it will (all of it) be passed around as argument around functions.

Which is better ?

Comment: It really depends. If all your functions can be grouped into a class, then class fields would be an acceptable way of making the data available to all class functions. Otherwise, I'd say extremely large data should almost certainly be passed by const reference, assuming the data itself is not modified in the functions.

Comment: The data itself is modified... So if I can group all functions into the class, it would be the same as having them all local to "main" ?

Comment: I don't think there's much (if any) difference between the two implementations in terms of speed or memory usage. Since either way you're not creating any extra copies of the data unless you pass by value (which almost certainly should not be done with huge data).

Comment: Thank you. If you'd like to post an answer, I'd like to accept it.

Comment: C++11?  Have you heard of move semantics?  You can write code where the data is passed in by move, and is returned by move, with next to no overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want unit testing, you cannot "have private data that all the functions can access" because then, all of that data would be a part of each test case.

So, you must think about each function, and define exactly on which part of the data it works. As for function parameters and return values, it's very simple: use pass-by-value for small objects, and pass-by-reference for large objects.

You can use a guesstimate for the threshold that separates small and large. I use the rule "8 is small, anything more is large" but what is good for my system cannot be equally good for yours.

Answer (score 1):

This seems more like a general question about OOP. Split up your data into logically grouped concepts (classes), and place the code that works with those data elements with the data (member functions), then tie it all together with composition, inheritance, etc.

Your question is too broad to give more specific advice.

Comment: I have added to my question, to make it more clear. It is not a "read the book, then create a couple of classes" question. There is absolutely no way to break this into logically grouped concepts, it is already broken down as far as it goes. I have pulled as many member functions as I could, based on functionality, without having to carry around the entire data amount. The question is: will I not impact performance too much if I make functions that pass the entire data ?